# Запрос Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть модель "User", в которой есть поле `username` и зависимая модель "Friend", которая содержит `username` друзей. Как получить всех "не друзей"?

```
@user = User.find_by username: current_user.username - текущий пользователь
@users = User.where.not(username: current_user.username) - все пользователи кроме текущего
@friends = @user.friends.all - все друзья
```

соответственно, нужно получить:

```
@notfriends = @users - @friends" по полю username
```

Пробовал так:

```
@notfriends = @users.where.not(username: @friends.username)
```

Естественно не получалось, потому что:

> undefined method `username' for Friend

Как сформулировать этот подзапрос, чтобы обращение шло не к объекту, а ко всем входящим в него сущностям?

Все что пришло в голову - цикл в экшене, который проходится запросом по всем экземплярам `@friends` по `username`.

```
@friends.each do |friend|
  @notfriends = @users.where.not(username: friend.username)
end
```

Однако хотелось бы сделать это не таким сооружением, а одним запросом.

Answer (score 2):

```
@notfriends = @users.where.not(username: @friends.username)
```

**Э-э-эх, почти-почти!** Нужно было всего лишь сделать [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-select) на имена пользователей:

```
@notfriends = @users.where.not(username: @friends.select(:username))
```

Получится запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM ...)
```

Техника называется "подзапрос". Если придумывать решение на SQL, такой вариант напрашивается сходу.

ActiveRecord сам использует `IN` (или `NOT IN`), когда в качестве значения указывается коллекция значений, будь то массивом или подзапросом. Понятно, что у `@friends` (`ActiveRecord::Relation` на модели `Friend`) метода `username` нет, но вдумайтесь в имя метода: у коллекции пользователей **не один** юзернейм!

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант, почему-то ничего не возвращает.

Comment: @ВалентинАндреев какой SQL из этого получается?

Comment: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" != $1) AND ("users"."username" NOT IN (SELECT "friends"."username" FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."user_id
" = $2))  [["username", "One"], ["user_id", 4]]

Comment: @ВалентинАндреев выглядит правильно: достать всех пользователей, у которых `username` не равен `"One"` и не находится среди `friends.username`, у которых `friends.user_id = 4`. Либо я неправильно понимаю вашу логику, либо это именно то, что вам и нужно. А если это ничего не возвращает, то у вас данные такие.

Comment: Данные действительно кривоватые (некоторые созданы для проверки через консоль), часть полей пустые, но @notfriends = @users.where.not(username:@friends.map(&:username)) - сработало как надо. Надо будет посмотреть, когда нормально все сделано будет.

Comment: @ВалентинАндреев а приведите столбцы таблицы Friends, я что-то не совсем понимаю, как у вас моделируются две стороны дружбы. Может, проблема там. Или даже сами модели.

Comment: [#<Friend id: 2, username: nil, user_id: 4, created_at: "2016-09-14 08:43:49", updated_at: "2016-09-14 08:43:49">, #<Friend id: 3, username: nil, user_id: 
4, created_at: "2016-09-14 08:45:05", updated_at: "2016-09-14 08:45:05">]>

Comment: @ВалентинАндреев охм... я правильно понимаю, что две стороны в "дружбе" у вас обозначены в `user_id` и `username`? Немного странное решение, ну да ладно.

Comment: Я просто пока решил не усложнять и дружба - односторонняя у меня, user has_many friends и все на этом. А username - хранит имена всех друзей.

Comment: @ВалентинАндреев я только что описал, где там у вас две стороны, у каждой записи и дружбе есть "начало" и "конец" :) In that "друзья" у вас образуют [ориентированный граф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вам придется воспользоваться SQL-конструкцией `NOT IN(...)`, операторов равно или не равно здесь недостаточно. Один из возможных вариантов может выглядеть таким образом

```
@notfriends = @users
  .where('username NOT IN(?), @friends.username)
  .where.not(username: current_user.username)
```

Лучше `@friends.username` и `current_user.username` предварительно объединить в один массив, чтобы в SQL-запросе осталось только одно `NOT IN(...)` условие. Еще лучше, вместо `username`, использовать идентификаторы `id`.

Comment: Все действительно решалось через NOT_IN, нашел массу разных вариантов запроса использовал такую:   @notfriends = @users.where.not(username:@friends.map(&:username))